# drilldown maps and funnell charts on the same page using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am having some issues with the combination of  drilldown maps with funnell charts using highcharts . My requirement is : I need to display drilldown maps in one div and funnell charts in another div .

But only drill down maps rendering correctly on the page, but funnell chart not rendering.

Javascript used :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
```

HTML DIV section :

```
<div id="drilldownmap">
<div id="funnell">
```

Data :

```
$(function () {

    var data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all']),
    // Some responsiveness
    small = $('#drilldownmap').width() < 400;

// Set drilldown pointers
$.each(data, function (i) {
    this.drilldown = this.properties['hc-key'];
    this.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
});

// Instanciate the map
$('#drilldownmap').highcharts('Map', {
    chart : {
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {

                if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                    var chart = this,
                        mapKey = 'countries/us/' + e.point.drilldown + '-all',
                        // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
                        fail = setTimeout(function () {
                            if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
                                chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-frown"></i> Failed loading ' + e.point.name);

                                fail = setTimeout(function () {
                                    chart.hideLoading();
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }, 3000);

                    // Show the spinner
                    chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>'); // Font Awesome spinner

                    // Load the drilldown map
                    $.getScript('http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', function () {

                        data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);

                        // Set a non-random bogus value
                        $.each(data, function (i) {
                            this.value = i;
                        });

                        // Hide loading and add series
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        clearTimeout(fail);
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                            name: e.point.name,
                            data: data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}'
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }


                this.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
            },
            drillup: function () {
                this.setTitle(null, { text: 'USA' });
            }
        }
    },

    title : {
        text : ''
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'USA',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        y: 50,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        }
    },

    legend: small ? {} : {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#E6E7E8',
        maxColor: '#005645'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        map: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#EEDD66'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series : [{
        data : data,
        name: 'USA',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
        }
    }],

    drilldown: {
        //series: drilldownSeries,
        activeDataLabelStyle: {
            color: 'white',
            textDecoration: 'none'
        },
        drillUpButton: {
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                x: 0,
                y: 60
            }
        }
    }
});


    $('#funnell').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Conversion funnel',
            x: -50
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                },
                neckWidth: '30%',
                neckHeight: '25%'

                //-- Other available options
                // height: pixels or percent
                // width: pixels or percent
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Unique users',
            data: [
                ['Website visits',   15558],
                ['Carts',       2017],
                ['Checkouts', 608],
                ['Orders',    368]
            ]
        }]
    });     

});
```

It would be great if someone could help me to resolve this issue??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `highmaps.js` is causing a conflict here. Use

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/map.src.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
```

And place

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/map.src.js"></script>
```

The complete list of script refs in `<head>` tag should look like this:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/map.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
```

This should get the job done.

Comment: Had same problem recently, finally found that they explain this in the docs, here:  http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started  some other possibly helpful info there as well.